# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I have procedure

```
create procedure dbo.updateView(@cobdate datetime)
as
begin
    Update hir_view set ValidTo=@cobdate where  HierarchyId in (
      select distinct HierarchyId from hir_organisation where ValidTo<getDate() and HierarchyId not in (
        select HierarchyId from hir_organisation where ValidTo>getDate()
      ) 
    ) and ValidTo>getDate()

end
go
```

whenI try to call this using

```
exec updateView(
convert(
dateTime,'20160209')
);
```

i get the error stating 
Lookup Error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 34, Server DSLNPHX02, Line 18 - Sybase Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.

I am not sure where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct, have you tried to run the update command like this

```
convert(dateTime,'20160209') 

 Update hir_view set ValidTo=convert(dateTime,'20160209')  where  HierarchyId in (
      select distinct HierarchyId from hir_organisation where ValidTo<getDate() and HierarchyId not in (
        select HierarchyId from hir_organisation where ValidTo>getDate()
      ) 
    ) and ValidTo>getDate()
```